# IPhone landscape and portrait

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I new to iphone app development i am trying to make simple app that contain registration page.

The registration view controller contain 10 textfield that are created on the uiscrollview using pro grammatically it working fine when it is in  portrait mode ,when device changed to landscape mode,
textfield and scroll view coming in bad design and try to overcome this problem by using authorisizing property
not worked well.

plz help me to get out of this problem and i want my app should support both landscape and portrait mode.

Comment: Show the code you have and a screenshot of what goes wrong

Comment: See [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) link. It might help you.